# How can I obtain a list of images/files with a compression type of LZW.

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, powershell, cmd

Does anybody have an idea of how to get a list of files that have an image compression type of LZW?

**The reason:** it seems that Adobe has issues with putting together a PDF from images where the compression type are different. You can get routine error message of "Insufficient data for image". I know I have weeded it down to an image with an LZW compression type. All the other images are fine but when it encounters that LZW image I will get that error. I know it's that one because IF I change that image from LZW to the same as the others it works the Adobe Reader works fine rendering.

So, the challenged I am faced with is getting a list of images that have the LZW compression and running them through a process to convert to CCITT T.6. (that conversion part I already have down). It's just how can I do like a directory and get all the files that have the LZW compression type on an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of LZW files and iterate the list and convert.

eg:

```
Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\TestDir\")
Dim filelist As IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles("*.LZW")


For Each file as IO.FileInfo In filelist
    <convert>
Next
```

Comment: No, I'm not looking for files with an extension of .lzw. I'm looking for like .tif or .tiff files that have a compression ratio of LZW which one would see using the Details tab when looking at a image file.

Comment: Ok I got what you are after. check this if it helps you (http://forums.adobe.com/thread/599614)  This uses ExifTool which is free so I hope it'll be helpful

Comment: That was great information and I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please put the actual answer into the body of your question? Links have an unfortunate tendency to break.

Answer (score 0):

after finding your images in directory, you can use this code to get compression type of each image (this method is zero-base, and if not find compression type returns -1 ) :

```
    private static int GetCompressionType(Image image)
    {
        // meaning of result :
        // 1 = No compression
        //  2 = CCITT modified Huffman RLE
        //  32773 = PackBits compression, aka Macintosh RLE

        //  Additionally, the specification defines these values as part of the TIFF extensions:

        //  3 = CCITT Group 3 fax encoding
        //  4 = CCITT Group 4 fax encoding
        //  5 = LZW
        //  6 = JPEG ('old-style' JPEG, later overridden in Technote2)

        //  Technote2 overrides old-style JPEG compression, and defines:

        //  7 = JPEG ('new-style' JPEG)

        //  Adobe later added the deflate compression scheme:

        //  8 = Deflate ('Adobe-style')

        //  The TIFF-F specification (RFC 2301) defines:

        //  9 = Defined by TIFF-F and TIFF-FX standard (RFC 2301) as ITU-T Rec. T.82 coding, using ITU-T Rec. T.85 (which boils down to JBIG on black and white).
        //  10 = Defined by TIFF-F and TIFF-FX standard (RFC 2301) as ITU-T Rec. T.82 coding, using ITU-T Rec. T.43 (which boils down to JBIG on color).
         
        int compressionTagIndex = Array.IndexOf(image.PropertyIdList, 0x103);
        PropertyItem compressionTag = image.PropertyItems[compressionTagIndex];
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(compressionTag.Value, 0);
    }
```